# Bootstrap Fluid Layout preserve ratio on small screens

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, fluid-layout

I am trying to build a clean fluid layout using twitter bootstrap, that preserves the relative ratio of the spans whatever the screen size.

I'm not sure this is possible in a clean way (a hack around it is to create html tables), but I am not interested in dirty hacks, the point is to write clean code.

So the idea is that on the bootstrap website they give the impression that this is possible:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#layouts

(try making your browser window small and you will see the fluid layout maintain it's relative ratio even whilst reducing to max (they used different code on the website since the class names are different)

But then when you download the fluid layout demo, if you resize the window to something small everything stacks up and I have not found a way to avoid that:

http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/examples/fluid.html

I'm thinking it's not possible, but was wondering if maybe someone knew something about this.

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

This behaviour is due to the inclusion of `bootstrap-responsive.css`. In narrow windows (`< 767px`), this [stacks up columns](https://github.com/twitter/bootstrap/blob/master/less/responsive-767px-max.less). So, if you really want to not have that behavior, just don't include `bootstrap-responsive.css`.

Comment: The idea is that i wanted to preserve it. I was building with icons that could take very little space. This is not available in bootstrap right now so i'm working on writing a patch